# C Linux pthreads: sending data from one thread to another using shared memory gives unexpected result

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, shared-memory

I am writing a program that will transfer 50 integers from one thread to another using shared memory and upon receiving the integers the receiver thread will print them.

The code compiles without any errors or warnings but when I run it I get the following output:

```
pthread_create() for thread 1 returns: 0
pthread_create() for thread 2 returns: 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <string.h>

//define declarations
#define SIZE     50

//function declarations
void *send_data();
void *receive_data();

int main()
{
     pthread_t thread1;
     pthread_t thread2;
     int ret_val_t1;
     int ret_val_t2;

     //create thread1
     ret_val_t1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, send_data, NULL);
     if(ret_val_t1)
     {
         fprintf(stderr,"Error - pthread_create() return value: %d\n",ret_val_t1);
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     //create thread2
     ret_val_t2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, receive_data, NULL);
     if(ret_val_t2)
     {
         fprintf(stderr,"Error - pthread_create() return value: %d\n",ret_val_t2);
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     printf("pthread_create() for thread 1 returns: %d\n",ret_val_t1);
     printf("pthread_create() for thread 2 returns: %d\n",ret_val_t2);

     //wait untill threads are done with their routines before continuing with main thread
     pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
     pthread_join( thread2, NULL); 

     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void *send_data(){
        int shmid;
    int *array;
    int i = 0;
    int SizeMem;
    key_t key = 12345;

    SizeMem = sizeof(*array)*SIZE;

    shmid = shmget(key, SIZE*sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT);

    array = (int *)shmat(shmid, 0, 0);


    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
          array[i] = i;
    }

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
            printf("\n%d---\n", array[i]);
    }

    printf("\nWritting to memory succesful--\n");

    shmdt((void *) array);
}

void *receive_data(){
    int shmid;
    int *array;
    int i = 0;
    key_t key = 12345;

    shmid = shmget(key, SIZE*sizeof(int), IPC_EXCL);

    array = shmat(shmid, 0, SHM_RDONLY);

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        {
            printf("\n%d---\n", array[i]);
        }

        printf("\nRead to memory succesful--\n");

        shmdt((void *) array);
}
```

Comment: Why you would use SysV shared memory to transfer data between threads of the same process is beyond me.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing as @EOF. Is this simply an exercise in using shared memory? I admittedly don't know much about shared memory, but my thought was it was used for sharing data between different processes

Comment: @EOF &yano This is just simply an exercise.

Comment: @Nikolaj Even so, I would not advise using SysV shared memory. The equivalent POSIX facilities are much more sane and usable.

Comment: In that case, I'd change the exercise (if you have the ability) to setting up shared memory between 2 processes.. just don't think there's a practical time you'd ever share memory like this between threads in a single process.

Comment: If you're going to use shared memory, at least create and attach to the shared memory before you create the threads.  Otherwise, you have race conditions about which thread is going to do what.

Comment: Do check the return values of shmget(2) as they return `-1` with `errno == EPERM`.  Are you enabled to allocate shared memory segments?

Answer (score 1):

Use [the `ipcs` utility](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ipcs.1.html) and look at the output from `ipcs -m`

Per [the shmget man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html):

> SYNOPSIS         top
>
> ```
>    #include <sys/ipc.h>
>    #include <sys/shm.h>
>
>    int shmget(key_t key, size_t size, int shmflg);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **In addition to the above flags, the least significant 9 bits of
>          shmflg specify the permissions granted to the owner, group, and
>          others**.  These bits have the same format, and the same meaning, as
>          the mode argument of open(2).  Presently, execute permissions are not
>          used by the system.

In line of code

```
shmid = shmget(key, SIZE*sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT);
```

the "the least significant 9 bits of shmflg" are set to zero.

No one has permissions to read/write your shared memory segment.

This would be better:

```
shmid = shmget(key, SIZE*sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0600 );
```

That would give the owning user read/write permission.

Comment: @Nikolaj What's the output from `ipcs -m`?  You're also not checking any return values for errors.  Since you don't have read or write access, your `shmat()` call may very well be failing.

Comment: `ipcs -m` output showed that there is no shared memory allocated.

Comment: That doesn't matter too much, as the creator always has write acces to the resource.  This is the first locking method implemented in unix (and the unique before v7)  As the memory segment is created in the process and used internally only, write access is warranted, even if mod mask is set to `0`.

Comment: No shared memory allocated is probably the effect of the `SIGSEGV` being fired before the shared memory is created.

Comment: @Nikolaj If `ipcs -m` doesn't show any shared memory segments, that means your call to `shmget()` is failing since your code never deletes/removes any shared memory segment.

Answer (score 1):

Here in this situation, shared memory is a costly affair. And you are trying to access from the same process, there is no benefit here.

The better way to handle your situation is:

**Threads of a parent process, will have access to parent process heap memory. This is simple concept to use. Create a heap object for the parent process and share across your threads.**

As said in many comments, shared memory is one of the "Inter Process Communication" communication concept, like pipes or named pipes or message queue etc....

If you are using for practice, then it is OK. But as apart of PROD use, this is a costly affair.

If you do not apply locks and access restriction to your mapped/shared memory properly, and you are not behind a secured firewall, then you are welcoming attackers.

Comment: I am using this just as an exercise.

Comment: That's fine. I added this as an information sake :)

Answer (score 1):

One race condition arises from your code.  Your second thread can get cpu first and try to use a non yet created memory segment.  As it doesn't exist, and as you don't check for errors, you can get a `SIGSEGV` from trying to access memory at `NULL` address.

You have to put synchronization devices that forbid the second thread to get to the shared memory access before it has been created and filled with data.  Something like.

```
pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_cond_t shm_created_and_filled;
```

then in `main` you initialize the `lock` and `shm_created_and_filled`.

in the writing thread you will create the shared memory segment and write the numbers, finally locking and signalling the `shm_created_and_filled` condition variable.  In the reading thread you first lock the `lock` variable and then wait for the `shm_created_and_filled` condition.  There's still a little race condition in which the first thread runs and signals the `shm_created_and_filled` condition before the reading thread waits for it (it will lose the condition) but I have left it as an exercise for the reader.